# PHP: как сгруппировать массив по ключу?

Tags: php, алгоритм

Подскажите, как можно сгруппировать массив в PHP:

```
  $arr = array (
       0 => array (
             'test1' => '1',
              ),
       1 => array (
             'test2' => '2',
              ),
       2 => array (
             'test3' => '3',
              ),
       3 => array (
             'test3' => '4',
              )
  );
```

Нужно сгруппировать по ключу `test3` таким образом, чтобы он остался ключом, а значения стали массивом для этого ключа.

Например:

```
  $arr = array (
       0 => array (
             'test1' => '1',
              ),
       1 => array (
             'test2' => '2',
              ),
       2 => array (
             'test3' => array('3', '4')
              )
  );
```

Comment: Создаёте новый массив, циклом перебираете старый массив и заполняете новый. В чём проблема? Как пытались?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

От руки

```
function groupByKey(&$arr, $recurs = true, $full_recurs = true) {
    $new_arr = array();
    foreach ($arr AS $val) {
        foreach ($val AS $key=>$value) {
            if (is_array($value) && $recurs) $value = groupByKey($value, $full_recurs);
            $new_arr[$key][] = $value;
        }
    }
    return $new_arr;
}
```

Comment: https://wtools.io/php-sandbox/ga